# How to set the Scaffold Drawer Width in JetpackCompose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

We can have Navigation Drawer in JetpackCompose by using `Scaffold` as below

```
Scaffold(
    drawerContent = { Text(text ="Drawer") }
) {}
```

[image]

I want to make the width of the drawer smaller. How can I do so?

Comment: I created a bug report for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177799274

Comment: @Elye check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68957817/12258661)

Answer (score 12):

You can modify the shape (including width and height) using `drawerShape` parameter in [Scaffold](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Scaffold(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldState,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material.FabPosition,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1)) method.

So for instance

```
 Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    drawerContent = { Text("Drawer content") },
    drawerShape = customShape(),
    content = {inner padding -> /* Body*/}
)
```

Then your customShape function

```
fun customShape() =  object : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
        ): Outline {
            return Outline.Rectangle(Rect(0f,0f,100f /* width */, 131f /* height */))
     }
 }
```

You can also use [Outline.Rounded](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Outline.Rounded) to get rounded corners

Comment: May be the best solution at the moment until a property for modifying drawer width is hopefully added to Scaffold. My only worry is if creating a Shape inside Composable functions could lead to slowdowns. I've tested that the above code works, but haven't profiled it yet in a real app.

Comment: @kabumere I don't think it would slow down the app since internally, various composable functions use Material shapes  (including the default `drawerShape` here; I'll check my pc and get the actual shape) which are actually functions similar to what I provided. Nonetheless, you can always make `customShape` a `val` and  not a `fun` so the `Shape` object would be created once

Comment: Yeah, mine was a val inside of a Composable function. I just started using Compose, so I guess I'm still wrapping my head around what gets re-called during recomposition and what doesn't.

Comment: This work if you want the drawer to be smaller. but if you want it to be larger (ex: full screen width). The drawer looks like it is larger but the content is still limited. All is truncaded. Any one have any idea on how to solves that ?

Comment: @BigDan That depends on the layout you used as `drawerContent`. You should modify the properties of that composable to extend it

Comment: How would you fill full screen height?

Comment: @kc_dev `return Outline.Rectangle(Rect(0f,0f,100f /* width */, size /* height */))`

Comment: How to use it if I need Rtl support?

Comment: @Roman I guess it already does since you're setting just the width and height

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks. I have to point out that `Rect(0f,0f,100f,131f)` made the drawer too small. I would suggest to use `Rect(0f,0f,size.width * 0.8f, size.height * 0.6f)`. You can change the proportion parameters (0.8f & 0.6f) as you wish. You will have to set the same proportion for the lazyColumn inside drawerContent as well. Otherwise some content could be cropped off from the drawer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example drawing a `Scaffold` custom shape.

**1. Spec exact size.**

```
Scaffold(
    drawerShape = NavShape(400.dp, 0f)
)
```

**2. Spec size by percent (half screen).**

```
Scaffold(
    drawerShape = NavShape(0.dp, 0.5f)
)
```

**Custom shape class**

```
class NavShape(
    private val widthOffset: Dp,
    private val scale: Float
) : Shape {

    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        return Outline.Rectangle(
            Rect(
                Offset.Zero,
                Offset(
                    size.width * scale + with(density) { widthOffset.toPx() },
                    size.height
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished that by:

**#1 - Setting to the Drawer's content Modifier a max width:**

```
@Composable
fun MyDrawerContent(){
     Column(Modifier.fillMaxHeight().width(300.dp)) {
          ...
```

**#2 - Setting the Scafold's drawer colors to Transparent + no Elevation**

```
Scaffold(
     drawerBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
     drawerContentColor = Color.Transparent,
     drawerElevation = 0.dp,
     drawerContent = {
          MyDrawerContent()
     },
     ...
```

**Note:** Only problem I faced is if you touch on the transparent area the drawer does not closes as it used to. Siding it to close works perfectly though.
It's a workaround...

Answer (score -3):

```kotlin
Scaffold(
      topBar = {
          topBar()
      },
      scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
      drawerContent = {
          drawer()
      },
      drawerGesturesEnabled = true
  ) { innerPadding ->
      NavigationHost(navController = navController)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried adding a modifier inside your drawer composable ?

Something like this:

```kotlin
Scaffold(drawerContent = { 
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.9f){
            Text(text = "Drawer") 
        }
    }) {}
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(. This just set the content width within the drawer. The drawer width is still the same.

Comment: @Elye ah right, maybe don't use `Scaffold` but `ModalDrawerLayout` directly, that way you can use its `modifier`

Comment: @ CyrilFind, It won't work with Modal drawer. Modal drawer represents the entire screen along with nav menu, not just the nav menu.