# How to change the drawer size in ModalDrawer (Jetpack compose)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way to change the drawer size in ModalDrawer? I spent my whole day looking for it but couldn't find any way

Comment: can you provide a design or drawing of the thing that you want to implement so that it will be easy for us to help

Comment: i just wanna know a way to change the drawer size(width), i havent planned the content but it can be anything; a text, image

Comment: sorry i did not get that,  could you provide a drawing of the expected output and the current output?\

Comment: Here is the same exact duplicate of this question where there is the diagram of what i want to do - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65305734/how-to-set-the-scaffold-drawer-width-in-jetpackcompose

Comment: Check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68957817/12258661 here